# How to monitor set/array changes in RxJS observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs

In Angular, I have a list of selectable items using checkbox inputs with `(click)="onSelectItem($event, item)`:

```js
@Input() public selectedItems$: EventEmitter<Set<any>>;
private selectedItems = new Set<any>();

public onSelectItem(event: any, item: any) {
    if (event.target.checked){
        this.selectedItems.add(item);
    } else {
        this.selectedItems.delete(item);
    }
    this.selectedItems$.emit(new Set(this.selectedItems));
}
```

These selected items are observed from another component using `selectedItems$` and displayed in a chart. However, the chart (from [`angular-highcharts`](https://github.com/cebor/angular-highcharts)) only have an API to add new series and remove a series using an index.

How can I observe `selectedItems$` to detect added items and removed items? Moreover, I need to keep track of the indexes of the items in order to remove them at the right index.

Comment: What about using an `Array<any>`?

Comment: Yes I could use an array. It should not make a significant difference as `Sets` are arranged by order of insertion.

Answer (score 0):

We can take advantage of `pairwise()` to build up a `Map` of indexes (`seriesMap`) as follows:

```js
@Input() public selectedItems$ = new EventEmitter<Set<any>>();
private seriesMap = new Map<any, number>();
private seriesLength = 0;

this.selectedEvaluations$.pipe(
    startWith(new Set()), // used so that pairwise emits the first value immediately
    pairwise(), // emit previous and current value
    map(([pv, cv]) => {
        let removed = new Set<any>([...pv].filter(x => !cv.has(x)));
        let added = new Set<any>([...cv].filter(x => !pv.has(x)));
        return [removed, added]
    }),
    tap(([removed, added]) => {
        for (const item of removed) {
            const idx = this.seriesMap.get(item);
            this.seriesMap.delete(item);
            for (const [key, value] of this.seriesMap) {
                if (value > idx) {
                    this.seriesMap.set(key, value-1);
                }
            }
            // this.chart.removeSeries(idx);
            this.seriesLength--;
        }
        for (const item of added) {
            // this.chart.addSeries(...);
            this.seriesMap.set(evaluation, this.seriesLength++);
        }
    })
)
```

Comment: This is the solution I came up with. I am very interested in simpler alternatives.